# В чем отличие __proto__ от prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

Пытаюсь разобраться с наследованием в js и никак не могу понять для чего нужен prototype если есть `__proto__`. Как я понял(из того материала что изучал), prototype - просто ссылается на `__proto__`, так ли это? Если - да, то какой смысл в prototype?

Comment: Первая ссылка в гугле https://habrahabr.ru/post/140810/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Свойство `prototype` имеет смысл только у конструктора

> Свойство с именем `prototype` можно указать на любом объекте, но особый смысл оно
>   имеет, лишь если назначено функции-конструктору.
>
> Само по себе, без вызова оператора `new`, оно вообще ничего не делает,
>   его единственное назначение – указывать `__proto__` для новых объектов.

Источник: https://learn.javascript.ru/new-prototype

Comment: `__proto__` - Это не поле объекта, и на самом деле его нельзя указать. Это геттер и сеттер, которые устанавливают значение внутреннего поля, и вызовы которых вполне заменяемы вызовами других функций